# Pairwise independence of Random variables does not imply indendence

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> > Show by a counterexample that for a family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of random variables the independence of all pairs $(X_i,X_j)$ with $i,j\in I, i\neq j$ does not imply the independence of the family (It is enough to consider $\mbox{card}(I)=3$.).

Hello, I am searching for a simple example. The professor gave the hint that one might consider random variables which only can take two different values, but I do not know exactly what is meant.

*By the way:*

We call the family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of random variables independent, if $(\sigma(X_i))_{i\in I}$ is independent, whereat we call a family $(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}$ with $\mathcal{E}_i\subset\mathcal{A}$ independent, if for any finite subset $I_0\subset I$ and any choice $E_i\in\mathcal{E}_i, i\in I_0$, it is
$$
\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i\in I_0}E_i)=\prod_{i\in I_0}\mathbb{P}(E_i).
$$

Comment: [Press me](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Pairwise+independence&l=1) and read the example.

Comment: I know that example but I would like to know what is here the probability space and on which probability spaces the three random variables are defined resp. which are the probability spaces in the image.

Comment: I want to use our definition, in other words but do not see the connection in every detail.

Comment: Well, for three random variables that are taking values in sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ you can always pick $\Omega = A\times B\times C$. In your case, $\Omega = \{0,1\}^3$, $\mathcal F = 2^\Omega$ and the probability measure is written in the example. Is it more clear now?

Comment: I do not like this example. I would prefer an example where the three random variables are not put together to a fourth random variable.

Comment: If you don't put together random variables (that is, if you don't define them on the same probability space), there is no dependence structure between them. You neither can claim that they are independent, nor that they are "dependent".

Comment: Maybe the following reformulation of the example will fulfil the OP's rather vague criteria for desirability. Alice and Bob play the game of matching pennies: Each of them flips a fair coin; Alice wins if the two results are the same (both heads or both tails) and otherwise Bob wins. The three random variables are (1) the result (heads or tails) of Alice's coin flip, (2) the result of Bob's coin flip, and (3) the winner (Alice or Bob). Every two of these are independent, but any two of them completely determine the remaining one.

Answer (score 2):

On the space $\Omega = \{-1,1\}^2$ with uniform probability, the three following random variables are pairwise independent but not mutually independent: $$X(\omega) = \omega_1,\qquad Y(\omega)=\omega_2,\qquad Z(\omega)=\omega_1\omega_2.$$